# NodeMCU http.get() and UTF-8 charset

Tags: http, utf-8, character-encoding, nodemcu

I am using the `http` module of the NodeMCU dev branch to make a GET request to the Google Calendar API. However, when I retrieve the events and parse answer, I get strange chars due to a non-proper encoding.

I tried to add `Accept-Charset: utf-8` in the header of the request, but the request fails (code=-1).

Is there a way to set the charset, or convert it afterwards in lua?

```
function bdayshttps(curr_date)
    if (string.len(curr_date) == 10) then
        http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"..
                    "<CalendarID>/events"..
                    "?timeMax="..curr_date.."T23%3A59%3A59-00%3A00"..
                    "&timeMin="..curr_date.."T00%3A00%3A00-00%3A00&fields=items%2Fsummary"..
                    "&key=<Google Calendar API key>", "Accept-Charset: utf-8", function(code, data)
            if (code < 0) then
              print("msg:birthdays error")
            else
              if (code == 200) then
                output = ""
                for line in data:gmatch"\"summary\": \"[^\n]*" do
                    output = output..line:sub(13, line:len()-1)..";"
                end
                print("bday:"..output)
              end
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

For obvious reasons, I erased the calendarID and API key.

EDIT:

The result of this code returns `msg:birthday error`, meaning the GET request returns a `code=-1`.

When replacing the `"Accept-Charset: utf-8"` by `nil` in the header, I get:

`LoÃ¯c Simonetti` instead of `Loïc Simonetti`.

Comment: Can you post the results you are receiving back?

Comment: I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 3):

The [API docs](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/http/#httpget) say that you need to append `\r\n` to every header you set. There's an example in the docs for `http.post()`.

Hence, instead of `"Accept-Charset: utf-8"` you should set `"Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n"`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Indeed, I don't have the `error=-1` code anymore: the `\r\n` did the trick. However, the charset is not working, here is the response:

`getbdays("2017-03-17")`
`> bday:LoÃ¯c Simonetti;`

Comment: @S.Blanc unless you can provide a (public) URL that shows that behavior for us to test I doubt you'll get a spot-on solution. Take note of http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode. Also keep in mind that it might be your editor (ESPlorer or so) that mangles characters. Try to dump bytes rather than characters and analyze what you get.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question (now that the response is working), it appears you are receiving back valid UTF8 Unicode.

`Loïc` corresponds to the following [UTF8 code units](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/): `4C 6F C3 AF 63`

`LoÃ¯c` has the following byte values in a common encoding ([CodePage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)): `4C 6F C3 AF 63`.

So my guess is the terminal or other device you're using to view the bytes is mangling things as opposed to your request/response being incorrect. Per @Marcel's link above too, Lua does not handle Unicode at all so this is about the best you can do (safely receive, store, and then send it back later)